# jQuery in ASP.NET not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and have been reading a lot of tutorials. I am having trouble with my script not returning my data. I have a page called, "users.aspx". In the code-behind page I have a method called, "getUserDetails()", which doesn't matter because it never gets called. My javascript gets called by clicking a td, and it sends the user id to the javascript function. That part works fine (passing in the parameter, "userId"). My div changes values, my colors change, but in the AJAX block, something is wrong. I want to send the userId value to my web method in the code-behind page to update my div contents. Based on various tutorials, this looked like the way to go.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDetails(userId) 
    {
        //Set selected menu colors       
        {
            $('td').css('backgroundColor', 'white'); //Reset all background colors to white
            $('#' + userId).css('backgroundColor', '#cccccc');
            $('#divrightcontent').html("Hi there");
        }

        //Get user details based on user id
        $.ajax({
            url: 'users.aspx/getUserDetails',
            data: { "uid": userId },
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 alert('We got the data');
                $("#divrightcontent").empty();
                $("#divrightcontent").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data, status, jqXHR) { $("#divrightcontent").html(jqXHR); }
        });
    }  
    </script>
```

Comment: I assume that you have created a static method in the code behind of users.aspx and made it a [WebMethod]. 
Are you getting any error when you do AJAX call? 
Did you try to debug the code? 
There is a possiblity that the code of getUserDeails is throwing error and not returning any data.

Comment: where is `msg` defined?

Comment: Please right click on page and run inspection tool before calling ajax and let us know if you're getting any error in Net tab.

Comment: msg was incorrect. I was debugging and forgot to change it back. I edited post.

Comment: Yes, I have a webmethod in the code behind. It never gets called though. In the PageLoad I do a Request.Form["uid"], but it is null. The issue isn't with the webmethod, but rather the ajax failing.

Comment: Any specific error details from the browser? Chromes console or network profiler, for example?

Comment: Please show your server-side code as well. Might be something obvious.